# How to return null value of sum function?

Tags: sql

I wrote a query which adds work hours of labors from last week.

```
select laborcode, sum(regularhrs) as TOTALACTUALS
from labtrans
where (laborcode='a' OR laborcode='b' OR laborcode='c' OR laborcode='d'
OR laborcode='e' OR laborcode='f') and (startdate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 7, getdate()), 0) and DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0))
group by laborcode;
```

Let's say labor "a" has 0 hours from last week, my result is:

```
b   25,5
c   37,25
d   24
e   48,5
f   25,5
```

but I want to get labor "a" too but with null value. For example:

```
a   0 (or null)
b   25,5
c   37,25
d   24
e   48,5
f   25,5
```

Comment: try this isnull(sum(name),0)

Comment: Do you have a table with your laborcodes?

Comment: @Muj That wont work, because you do not get a row with laborcode a

Comment: You should use appropriate `JOIN` your query with another table with labours.

Comment: ahh okay so you must reverse your query. `select laborcode, ISNULL(sum(regularhrs),0) as TOTALACTUALS from laborcode_table left join labtrans ON laborcode_table.laborId =  labtrans.laborId where (laborcode='a' OR laborcode='b' OR laborcode='c' OR laborcode='d'
OR laborcode='e' OR laborcode='f') and (startdate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 7, getdate()), 0) and DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0))
group by laborcode;` i think this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using conditional SUM

```
select laborcode
  , sum(CASE WHEN startdate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 7, getdate()), 0) and DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0) THEN regularhrs END) as TOTALACTUALS
from labtrans
where laborcode in('a','b','c','d','e','f') 
group by laborcode;
```

Or left join to a predifined list

```
SELECT l.laborcode, sum(d.regularhrs) as TOTALACTUALS
from (
     values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('f')  
     ) l(laborcode)
left join labtrans d on d.laborcode = l.laborcode and (d.startdate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 7, getdate()), 0) and DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0))
group by l.laborcode
```

Comment: The first one worked and was easy to understand, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Left join your grouped by values to a list of labourcodes:

```
select distinct b.labourcode, coalesce(a.TotalHours,0) as TotalHours
from labtrans b
left join 
(
    select a.laborcode, sum(a.regularhrs) as 
    from labtrans a
    where a.labourcode in ('a','b','c','d','e','f') 
    and a.startdate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 7, getdate()), 0) and DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
    group by a.laborcode
)
on a.labourcode = b.labourcode
```